# When converting number to string the value is being changed

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert a number to string in js/ts and find out that the string is different from the source number. Example:

```
const num = 60001100110011001100;
const str = num.toString(); // or '' + num - the same result
console.log(str); // '60001100110011000000'
```

Why does that happen? And how can I get the same value of the number but as a string?

Comment: `60001100110011001100 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER // true`